# How can I create two different app inside one angular project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular1.6

I am using angular 1 and I have two different apps with two different domains .. I want to put them on one angular project and make one form login for both of them ..some user can go to the first app and others can go to the other app depending on their profile type.
this is available on angular and how can I do this?

Comment: this has nothing to do to angular specifically. if you have them on different domains, then you should have the login form one of them. Use CORS to receive the second server information to keep a live session between two domains on each request. you need to add some headers on the second server such as withCredentials=true.

Comment: ok, I got it, thanks a lot.